# Adding some measurements into the plot

Tags: plotting

From [Godbeer et al, Modelling proton tunnelling in the adenine–thymine base pair](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2015/cp/c5cp00472a#!divAbstract):

[image: Godbeer, A. D., Al-Khalili, J. S., & Stevenson, P. D. (2015). Modelling proton tunnelling in the adenine–thymine base pair. Physical Chemistry Chemical Physics, 17(19), 13034–13044. doi:10.1039/c5cp00472a]

Hello,

Well, I have very similar graph like in the image. I am trying to add that additional measurments like deltaE and EB arrows. I couldnt find a way to express the question better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Take a look at [Epilog](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html). If you get stuck, post the code you have tried.

Comment: see also [Drawing Tools](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InteractiveGraphicsPalette.html) .

Answer (score 4):

You must add these graphical elements in an Epilog by hand. Here is an example how to do it:

```
d = {1, 0, 1, .5, 1};
pol = InterpolatingPolynomial[d, x];
Plot[pol, {x, 1, 5}, Epilog -> {
   Arrowheads[{-0.04, 0.04}],
   Arrow[{{3.7, -0.237}, {3.7, 0.236}}], 
   Arrow[{{2.5, -0.237}, {2.5, 1.02}}],
   Dashed,
   Line[{{0.5, -0.237}, {5, -0.237}}], Line[{{2, 1.02}, {3.5, 1.02}}],
    Line[{{3.5, 0.236}, {5, 0.236}}],
   Text[Style["E", 20], {2.7, 0.3}], Text[Style["Del", 20], {4, 0.1}]
   }]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First a data set that *looks like* the one behind the picture in OP:

```
SeedRandom[1]
dt = Table[ {x, Cos[5 Pi x/3]/(5 Pi x/3) + 1/2}, {x, Sort @ RandomReal[{0, 2}, 50]}];

ClearAll[iF]
iF = Interpolation[dt, 
  "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Automatic, "WarningMessage" -> False}];

listplot = ListPlot[dt, PlotMarkers -> {"\[Cross]", 20}, PlotStyle -> Black];

Show[Plot[iF[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick, Dotted]], listplot]

plot = Plot[iF[x], {x, 0, 2}, MeshFunctions -> {iF'[#] &}, 
   Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[15]], 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick, Dotted]];

Show[plot, listplot]
```

[image]

A convenient graphical trick to identify the extreme points is to use `{iF'[#]&}` as the option value for [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) and set `Mesh -> {{0}}`:

```
plot = Plot[iF[x], {x, 0, 2}, MeshFunctions -> {iF'[#] &}, 
   Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[15]], 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick, Dotted]];

Show[plot, listplot]
```

[image]

Now we can extract the coordinates of `Point`s from plot output and use them to add tangent lines passing through those points, annotated arrows marking the vertical displacements from a reference point etc.

First, a helper function to create custom arrowheads with labels:

```
ClearAll[arrowHeadsLabeled]
arrowHeadsLabeled[lbl_, side_: {1, 0}, dir_: {0, -1}, pos_: .5] := 
 Arrowheads[{{-.03, 0}, {.03, 1}, 
   {.03, pos, {Graphics[Text[lbl, {0, 0}, side, dir]], 1}}}]
```

***Example:***

```
Graphics[{arrowHeadsLabeled["LABEL 1"], Red, Arrow[{{1, 0}, {1, 4}}], 
  arrowHeadsLabeled["LABEL 2", {0, -1}, {1, 0}], Blue, 
  Arrow[{{3, -1}, {3, 3}}], 
  arrowHeadsLabeled[Style["LABEL 3", 16], {0, 1.5}, {1, 0}, .25], Green, 
  Arrow[{{4, 0}, {5, 3}}]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {-2, 5}}, 
 ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

Next, a function that annotates the output from `Plot` with `Mesh*` options as in the example above:

```
ClearAll[annotatedPlot]
annotatedPlot[plt_, labels_, disp_: 1.5] := 
 Module[{sortedextrema = SortBy[First]@Cases[Normal[plt], Point[x_] :> x, All], start, 
   xma, arrows, tangentlines},
  start = First@MinimalBy[Last]@sortedextrema; 
  xma = MovingAverage[Join[{PlotRange[plt][[1, 1]]}, 
      sortedextrema[[All, 1]], {PlotRange[plt][[1, 2]]}], {2, 1}];
  arrows = Arrow[Offset[{If[#[[1]] < start[[1]], -5, 10], 0}, #] & /@ 
     Partition[#, 2]] & /@ Thread[{Rest @ Most @ xma, start[[2]], 
         Rest @ Most @ xma, DeleteCases[sortedextrema, start][[All, 2]]}];
  tangentlines = Line /@ DeleteCases[
     Thread /@ Transpose[{Partition[xma, 2, 1] , sortedextrema[[All, 2]]}], start];
  Show[plt /. Point[_] -> {}, 
   Graphics[{Dashed, tangentlines, 
     Line[{{sortedextrema[[1, 1]], start[[2]]}, {sortedextrema[[-1, 1]], start[[2]]}}], 
     Black, Dashing[{}], 
     MapThread[{arrowHeadsLabeled[#, {disp, 0}], #2} &, {labels, arrows}]}], 
   ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]]
```

***Examples:***

Using `plot` and `listplot` from the first example above:

```
labels = {Style[Subscript[InputForm@E, B], 16], Style[∇InputForm@E, 16]};

Show[annotatedPlot[plot, labels], listplot, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
dt2 = Table[ {x, Cos[5 Pi x/3]/(5 Pi x/3) + 1/2}, {x, Sort@RandomReal[{0, 4}, 50]}];

ClearAll[iF2]
iF2 = Interpolation[dt2, 
    "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Automatic, "WarningMessage" -> False}];

listplot2 = ListPlot[dt2, PlotMarkers -> {"\[Cross]", 20}, PlotStyle -> Black];
plot2 = Plot[iF2[x], {x, 0, 4}, MeshFunctions -> {iF2'[#] &}, 
   Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[15]], 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick, Dotted]];

labels2 = labellist = Style[Subscript[∇InputForm@E, #], 16] & /@ Range[6];

Show[annotatedPlot[plot2, labels2, -1.5], listplot2]
```

[image]

A variation that takes a data set and labels as input:

```
ClearAll[annotatedListPlot]
annotatedListPlot[lbls_: Automatic, disp_: 1.5][data_, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[{Plot, ListPlot}]] := 
 Module[{lp = ListPlot[data, opts], 
   if = Interpolation[data, "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Automatic, 
       "WarningMessage" -> False}], plt, lblst}, 
  plt = Plot[if[x], {x, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}, 
    MeshFunctions -> {if'[#] &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, opts]; 
  lblst = lbls /. Automatic -> (ToString /@ 
       Range[Count[Normal@plt, _Point, All] - 1]); 
  Show[annotatedPlot[plt, lblst, disp], lp, opts]]
```

***Example:***

```
annotatedListPlot[labellist, -1.5][dt2, 
 PlotTheme -> {"Minimal", "OpenMarkersThick"}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]
```

[image]